# Is it a bug when pending edits by myself appear near the review button?

Tags: bug, suggested-edit

I've recently proposed an edit for the [ss-gb](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ss-gb) tag excerpt, after creating it. Some time after, the pending edit button appeared near the review queue button. When I clicked, the queue appeared empty, but the **button remained there**.

[image]

It still does, even after multiple clicks, as shown in the animation above.

Is this a known bug when my own edits appear as pending (given that I've already *reviewed* them by proposing them)?

Comment: That review number in the topbar is *full* of bugs.

Comment: Why not ask a question like this on meta.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Null the first link in Aegon's answer seems to address a concern similar to mine (although there OP has 10k queue broken). I'll post a link to this post under Shog's answer.

Comment: What I mean is that you should ask bug questions like this on MSE instead of a site meta, unless you think the bug is limited to that particular site. You're more likely to get a response from an SE employee at MSE and/or find that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Null I must admit it didn't occur to me. In any case, it should be fairly easy to migrate this to main meta even now if needed... right?

Comment: I don't think there's much point in migrating this now -- it'd probably just be closed as a duplicate. These kinds of questions *are* on-topic here on scifi meta, it's just that you're more likely to get an authoritative answer on MSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is a known caching issue and [status-bydesign](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Quoting [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238699/307083):

> **Caching. And some complicated eligibility rules.**
>
> Most of the time, **the top bar will indicate what's still TO DO for
>   the site, while the numbers under /review will indicate what's still
>   TO DO for you**. But when reviews are being done quickly, they can
>   become out-of-date briefly. The **system recalculates them every few
>   minutes, so generally they won't be out of date for too long**...
>
> ...But there are still some edge-cases where **there'll be items in a
>   queue that you aren't eligible to review but which are disqualified
>   because of tests too expensive for the system to run until/unless you
>   actually try to review them**.
>
> It's unlikely you'll encounter the latter very often, but if you see a
>   discrepancy hanging around for more than 5-10 minutes, chances are
>   that's what it is.

So what happened is, the topbar showed that a review was pending for the site to do. When you clicked it, System calculated your eligibility for the review and found out that you are not eligible for that review (Because it's your edit after all). So it showed you no pending edits.

Also see: Another one of Shog's answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266018/4029561).

Further reading: [Should I blame Caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

**Update:** In the new design rolled out for SO, it appears that they have fixed this issue by getting rid of the count altogether. Now the counts load when you click on review button, for every queue respectively.

[image]

I have left shog a comment to seek official confirmation. Will update if he replies. I have also created [a MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346615/4029561) to seek official confirmation from other sources if Shog is not available to comment.

**UPDATE 2:** Yes Shog has confirmed the new layout is supposed to be the fix for this issue. Quoting [him](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238698/does-the-review-queue-page-show-only-reviews-requiring-your-action-does-it-diff/238699?noredirect=1#comment954086_238699):

> Well... It's a fix, @NSNoob. It ain't ideal; the ideal implementation
>   would light up the indicator when - and only when - there are tasks
>   that you need to do when you haven't been reviewing for a while. But
>   it is an improvement: there's a delay, no bogus number, and a check
>   for some reasonably-sane number of pending tasks.

Comment: Thanks! It's been hanging on since I posted this, by the way, so you're right.